# Sorting an array of strings in a non-full ordering (Make sure element X is first, but do whatever with everything else)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, sorting

Following a [flask-react-app-tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project), I'm trying to push data from my simple *server.py* into the *App.js* and display it in a nice table.

I used the simplest table layout from [material-ui tables](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/) and I tweaked it as much as I could so it would be dynamic and the data will be controlled only by the server, meaning I could add / delete entries (rows) or entry params (columns) just in the server.

My problem is described in the `"TODO"` comments in the code, but I'll rewrite it here:

- How can I get the entry params from the server, and sort them, but not fully. e.g. the params are A B C, and I want A to be always first and C to be always last (in this case, it enforces an ordering of **A, B, C**, so even if the server later changes the params, and adds D to the bunch, the ordering will be **A, [B, D], C** (I don't care about the ordering of the params in [], as long as its consistent)?
- I think this should / must happen in the react app, but is it possible to sort it before-hand in the Python server? currently I'm returning a dict, which can't be sorted, but is an OrderedDict legit (i.e. valid AND a good idea)?

## App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';


export default function SimpleTableDisplayingServerData() {
    const [ data, SetData ] = useState(0);

    // TODO: (0) How can I make sure the data from useEffect is sorted? (at least have the "Name" column as the 1st column)
    // TODO: (0.0) How can I get the headers (like I did in the <TableHead>) as a const?
    // TODO: (0.1) How can I create a non-strict ordering in an array of strings? (i.e. make sure "A" is first, "D" is last, but all others can be wherever)
    // TODO: (0.2) Given that ordering, how can I order all my keys / values mappings (in the <TableRow>) accordingly?
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/bla').then(result => result.json()).then(d => {
            SetData(d)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table size="small" aria-label='simple table'>
                <TableHead> <TableRow> { Object.keys(data).map(k => <TableCell align='left'>{k}</TableCell> )} </TableRow> </TableHead>
                <TableRow> { Object.values(data).map(v => <TableCell align='left'>{v}</TableCell> )} </TableRow>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

## server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
from random import randint, random

app = Flask(__name__)

def create_entry():
    name = 'bla' + str(randint(0,20))
    cal = random()
    fat = random()
    carb = random()
    prot = random()

    return {
        "Name": name,
        "Calories": cal,
        "Fat": fat,
        "Carbs": carb,
        "Protein": prot,
    }

@app.route('/bla')
def bla():
    return create_entry()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the wanted order of the items and use only the most left and right values. for all other (unknown) values take zero.

```js
const
    order = { a: -Number.MAX_VALUE, c: Number.MAX_VALUE },
    values = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'];
    

values.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0));

console.log(...values);
```

Comment: How can I combine your answer with the mapping I have? I'm not sure how to (0) get the keys of data, (1) use your sore on them

Comment: @CIsForCookies, i have no idea of react.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple instead of a dictionary. That should work for you!